# Ajax parse json string is returning undefined,

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending a post data to get a json string back:

**My JSON string:**

```
{"error":false,"success":"Added Website","website_id":"12"}
```

My Ajax request:

```js
$('.publsher_add_website').on("submit", function() {
  show_loader();
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success == false) {
        ajax_error(data.error);
        hide_loader();
      } else {
        console.debug(data);
        console.log(data.error);
        console.log(data.success);
        console.log(data.website_id);
        location.href = site_url + "publisher/websites?added=" + data.website_id + "#modal-verify";
        hide_loader();
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      hide_loader();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Now, when I go to use the returned `data` all of them are undefined.I have used:

```
console.debug(data);
```

Which returns the json string above, but if I try to access them individually:

```
data.error;
data.success;
data.website_id;
```

They all return as `undefined` Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you aren't use `dataType`, so can you try doing `success: function(data) { data = JSON.parse(data);` as the first thing inside the `success` function?

Comment: Ahh. Silly mistake. Thank you.

Comment: I will answer it now.

Comment: I have written it as an answer, and after 10 mins, you can accept it. `:)` You are welcome! `:)`

Comment: Thanks mate. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided a `dataType` in your `$.ajax`, so AJAX treats the response as a `string`, not an object. So, inside the `success` function, do this first:

```
success: function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your json string to a json object to get your values:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```